# nginx everything - 301 to subdomain

Tags: nginx

Im having some troubles trying to redirect everything to subdomain on nginx. Im running a subdomain with cloudflare thats why I need to redirect the traffic to this subdomain.

*.soldadinhos.global -> site.soldadinhos.global

soldadinhos.global -> site.soldadinhos.global

How would I do that?

```
server {
    server_name site.soldadinhos.global;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/soldadinhos.global/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/soldadinhos.global/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}



server {
   server_name *.soldadinhos.global soldadinhos.global;
   listen 80;
   return 301 https://site.soldadinhos.global;
}
```

EDIT: I've altered the conf file, its working now but if I access www.soldadinhos.global/somefile.php it doesnt redirect to site.soldadinhos.global/somefile.php

Comment: What is exactly the subdomain setup you have with Cloudflare? Where is the origin server of that subdomain? Please provide a couple of source URL -> destination URL examples in your question to clarify the question.

Comment: Hey @TeroKilkanen I have site.soldadinhos.global setup at Cloudflare. Want to redirect *.soldadinhos.global and soldadinhos.global to site.soldadinhos.global.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
server {
    server_name *.example.com example.com;

    listen 80;

    return 301 http://site.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

You need to remove the `example.com` from your existing configuration.

Then you need to add corresponding DNS A records to your DNS that point to this server.

Comment: I've altered the conf file. Can you check the EDIT

Comment: Well, your question didn't state the fact that you want sub-URLs to be redirected too. Try my updated answer.